# navigating dom in htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am lost in HTML DOM. Using HTMLAgilityPack, how would I navigate the following nodes buried deep inside the DOM?

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td> Name: </td>
    <td> James </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> age: </td>
    <td> 33 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote the following sample code and it works great to extract list of questions from StackOverflow.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

            HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(s);

            HtmlNodeCollection items = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='question-hyperlink']");
            foreach (HtmlNode item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.InnerHtml);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```